# Google maps api v2 get polygon coordinate

Tags: coordinates, polygon, google-maps-api-2

I am a bit of a beginner at google maps api. I managed to let the user to draw a polygon on the map and then I want to get the coordinates on the drew polygon.

I have used the following segment of code but it gave me the following error **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getPath'**

this is the code that I used

```
function startShape() {


    initialize();
    document.getElementById('lat').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('lng').disabled = true;
  var polygon = new GPolygon([],"ff0000", 2, 0.7,"ff0000",0.2);
  startDrawing(polygon, "Shape " + (++shapeCounter_), function() {
    var cell = this;
    var area = polygon.getArea();
    cell.innerHTML = (Math.round(area / 10000) / 100) + "km<sup>2</sup>";
  });
  showcoor(polygon);
}




function startDrawing(poly, name, onUpdate) {

 map.addOverlay(poly);
  poly.enableDrawing(options);
  poly.enableEditing({onEvent: "mouseover"});
  poly.disableEditing({onEvent: "mouseout"});
  GEvent.addListener(poly, "endline", function() {
    //var cells = addFeatureEntry(name, color);
    //GEvent.bind(poly, "lineupdated", cells.desc, onUpdate);
    GEvent.addListener(poly, "click", function(latlng, index) {
      if (typeof index == "number") {
        poly.deleteVertex(index);
      } 
    });
  });


}


function showcoor (poly) {
GEvent.addListener(poly, "endline", function() {
    GEvent.addListener(poly, "click", function() {
    var str;
               var vertices = this.getPath();
              for (var i =0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
                var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
                str += xy.lat() +"," + xy.lng()+"<br />";
              }
              alert (str);
            });
            });
    }
```

Comment: You say you're using V3, but your code looks suspiciously V2ish (GPolygon, GEvent). Do you have somewhere you've posted all your code that we can take a look? Perhaps on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `getPath` method on the `GPolygon` object. See the [`GPolygon` reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GPolygon).

Instead, you'll need to use `getVertexCount()` and `getVertex(i)`.

```
for (var i = 0, I = this.getVertexCount(); i < I; ++i) {
  var xy = this.getVertex(i);
  str += xy.lat() + ', ' + xy.lng() + '<br />';
}
```